# Customise my wordpress site to have the add to cart button appear when someone hovers over the products. I have attached the scree

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, elementor

I have very beginner level understanding of wordpress, woocommerce and elementor. I am still learning a lot of things. I believe that the best way to learn is to imitate. So, I go through various themes and try to imitate their behaviour and appearance using Elementor. But, this particular theme caught my eye. The Add to cart button appears when someone hovers over the product image instead of always being there. Can you guys please help me figure this out or atleast point me in the right direction?

[This is how it should look when someone hovers over the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKL6F.jpg)
[image]

[This is how it looks when the mouse pointer is away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr3Vq.jpg)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="more">More info</a>
<?php if($available) {?>
    <a href="<?php $add_to_cart = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart_url id="'.$post->ID.'"]'); echo $add_to_cart; ?>" class="more">Buy now</a>
<?php } ?>
```

This code solves my problem as expected.

[WooCommerce documentation reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-15)

1. **Solution:** Add code in your theme's function.php file.

   ```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

   function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
     global $product;
     echo '<a href="URL">Add to cart</a>';
   }
   ```
2. **Solution:** Install Custom WooCommerce Add to Cart plugin

[Custom WooCommerce Add to Cart Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-text-on-add-to-cart-button-for-woocommerce/)

3. **Solution:** You can use hooks with shortcodes:

[custom add to cart button](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9)

Or create overrides for WooCommerce files in your own template